# A few questions about md5 collision in production

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashmap, md5, secret-key

I'm in a game company, and we use md5 algorithm to do the charge order check.

Here is how we do it:

1. On both the Pay-center server and our game server there is a common "secret-key".
2. Pay-center send an add game coin request to our game server.
   In which there are many conventional parameters and a special parameter named "sign"
3. When we received a request on the game server, we use md5("all the conventional parameters" + "secret key") to produce a result.
   If the result is equal to "sign" parameter, we'll consider this charge order a valid one.

---

My question are:

If someone blindly using a random-generated "pseudo-secret-key" to doing md5 computation with all other parameters to produce a sign.
And by coincidence, he made a valid sign with one of his "pseudo-secret-key".

1. How many times does he need to try to produce a valid sign for each group of "conventional parameters"?
2. How many chances are there the `pseudo-secret-key` is identical to my original `secret-key` when it happens to produce a valid `sign`?
3. If the `pseudo-secret-key` is different with my original `secret-key`, is it nearly impossible to use the `pseudo-key` to produce a valid sign using another different combinations of  `conventional parameters`?

Comment: What is the point to reason about this? Cannot you just update to a more secure hash function? How expensive can that be (development-cost-wise)? If you are going to submit to any kind of security audit, MD5 in a payment processing function will stand out unfavourably. I'm not arguing to blindly follow checklists, but MD5 is really quite deprecated.

Comment: Thi sisn't really a coding question - there's no example code, no clear error - it might be more fitting for http://crypto.stackexchange.com or http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Thilo, we have to deal with many other sdk pay-centers, and nearly all of them using md5() to do encryption.

Comment: It's been possible to produce deliberate collisions in MD5 for over ten years: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/15819/1427 - maybe he only needs to try once?  md5() isn't encryption...

Answer (score 1):

The basic: md5 hash result is uniformly distributed. That's a chance of 1 out of 2^128.

1. You can't tell exactly how many attempts he will need. You may, however, calculate the chances of colition in `t` attempts : `1 - (1 - 1 / (2 ^ 128)) ^ t`. For example, after 2^128 attempts he has a chance of about 1/3.
2. Depends on the range of your key.
3. Again, chances are `1/(2^128)`.